# An $O(n^2)$ is faster than an $O(n\log n)$ algorithm for small $n$

Tags: time-complexity

> If $n<100$ then $O(n^2)$ is more efficient, but if $n\ge 100$ then $O(n\log n)$ is more efficient.

I am sure that this statement is valid, but I don't know how to prove it or justify it. Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your statement is meaningless, since $O(n^2)$ and $O(n\log n)$ are just *upper bounds* on the time complexity. If you know that $A \leq 100$ and $B \leq 10$, you have absolutely no idea which is larger, $A$ or $B$.

Let us correct your statement to

> If $n<100$ then $\Theta(n^2)$ is more efficient, but if $n \geq 100$ then $\Theta(n\log n)$ is more efficient.

This statement still has no truth value, since we don't know which functions are represented by $\Theta(n^2)$ and by $\Theta(n\log n)$. What we do know is that for large enough $n$, the $\Theta(n\log n)$ algorithm would be more efficient.

Suppose you instantiate your statement with specific functions $f(n) = \Theta(n^2)$ and $g(n) = \Theta(n\log n)$. There is no reason to expect that there is a single crossover point. For example, take the following functions:
$$
f(n) =
\begin{cases}
100 & \text{if } n < 20, \\
n^2 & \text{if } n \ge 20
\end{cases} \\
g(n) =
\begin{cases}
50 & \text{if } n < 10, \\
200 & \text{if } 10 \le n < 20, \\
10^{300} n\log n & \text{if } n \ge 20
\end{cases}
$$
As you can see, $g(n)$ is faster for $n < 10$, and then for (astronomically) large enough $n$.

While such definitions are artificial, in practice we could have (say) $f(n) = 3n^2 + n\log n + 9n + 17$ and $g(n) = 10n\log n + 4\sqrt{n} + 50$, which might have several crossover points (I haven't checked).

Finally, even if there is a single crossover point, there is no reason to expect it to be exactly $n = 100$. The exact crossover point(s) depend on the functions $f(n),g(n)$. The only way to determine it is by running the two algorithms and comparing the running times.

Comment: So, every time it depends  on which function we use for Θ(nlogn) and Θ(n^2) ?

Comment: Right, the answer depends on the exact functions used.

Answer (score 1):

We have $O(n\log n) \subset O(n^2)$ i.e. any $f$ from $O(n\log n)$ is also in $O(n^2)$.

Let's take any pair from $O(n\log n)$, for example $f_1(n)=n$ and  $f_2(n)=n\log n$.  Firstly we can consider them as $f_1 \in O(n^2), f_2 \in O(n\log n)$ and then we can consider them as $f_2 \in O(n^2), f_1 \in O(n\log n)$. It turns out, we cannot say that a representative of one class is definitely better than another.

Even more - we can formulate the following true sentence :

for any $f$ from $O(n\log n)$ we can find "faster" $g$ from $O(n^2)$.

Answer (score -4):

$O(n\log n)$ is *always* faster.  On some occasions, a faster algorithm may require some amount of setup which adds some constant time, making it slower for a small $n$.

So in reality, $O(n^2 + i)$ *may* be faster than $O(n\log n + j)$ if $j$ is sufficiently larger than $i$ for small enough $n$.  There is certainly no number $n$ for which you can say there is definitely a crossover.

Note that we always ignore $i$ and $j$ in practice because big O notation is for when $n$ is large, so constants become increasingly meaningless and we only care about the fastest growing term.