# $O(n^2)$ and $O(n\log n)$ exercise

Tags: time-complexity

There is an  exercise which says : Al and Bob are arguing about their algorithms. Al claims his $O(n \log n)$-time method is always faster than Bob’s $O(n^2)$-time method. To settle the issue, they perform a set of experiments. To Al’s dismay, they find that if $n<100$, the $O(n^2)$-time algorithm runs faster, and only when $n\ge 100$ is the $O(n \log n)$-time one better. Explain how this is possible.

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/139111/an-on2-is-faster-than-an-on-log-n-algorithm-for-small-n/139116#139116

Answer (score 0):

Consider for Al $f_{Al} \in O(n \log n) $:

$$f_{Al}(n)=\begin{cases}n\log n, & \text{ when }n\lt 100 & \\
n  , &\text{ when }n \geqslant 100\end{cases}$$

For Bob let's take $f_{Bob}(n) \in O(n^2)$

$$f_{Bob}(n)=\begin{cases}n, & \text{ when }n\lt 100 & \\
n\log n  , &\text{ when }n \geqslant 100\end{cases}$$

Note also, that since for asymptotic relations it is only important what happens from some number to infinity, then Bob and Al are arguing in vain.

Comment: zkutch can you please explain it a little more?

Comment: Of course: please indicate exactly what you would like to be explained in more detail.

Comment: I cannot understand how this is possible (the result I mean not your solution.) they are just taking different functions?

Comment: Why not, if this answers question.

Comment: I understand. You helped me a lot. Thank you